# How to update a HasOne relationship when a HasMany relationship also exists with the same model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to define *both* a HasMany and HasOne relationship between the same two models in Eloquent.

My `Organization` class has many `Contact`s:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
}
```

And likewise, my `Contact` class reflects this relationship:

```
public function organization()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class);
}
```

But also, each `Organization` has exactly one "primary" `Contact`.  I am using a table column `organizations.primary_contact_id` to identify which one:

```
public function primaryContact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class, 'id', 'primary_contact_id');
}
```

From here, I'm stuck.  The reverse relationship in `Contact` already exists, so I wrote another function I thought would do the trick, figuring if I updated the value in the parent table, Eloquent would naturally fetch the corresponding record in the contacts table since I defined the relationship:

```
/**
 * @param \App\Contact
 */
public function setPrimaryContact($contact)
{
    $this->primary_contact_id = $contact->id;
    $this->save;
}
```

But it doesn't:

```
>>> $org = Organization::find(17)
=> App\Organization {#2923
     id: 17,
     name: "Test Org",
     primary_contact_id: 33,
   }
>>> $alice= $org->primaryContact
=> App\Contact {#2938
     id: 33,
     organization_id: 17,
     fname: "Alice",
     lname: "Abbot",
   }
>>> $bob = Contact::find(34)
=> App\Contact {#2939
     id: 34,
     organization_id: 17,
     fname: "Bob",
     lname: "Baker",
   }
>>> $org->setPrimaryContact($bob)
=> null
>>> $org
=> App\Organization {#2923
     id: 17,
     name: "Test Org",
     primary_contact_id: 34,
     primaryContact: App\Contact {#2938
       id: 33,
       organization_id: 17,
       fname: "Alice",
       lname: "Abbot",
     },
   }
```

You can see `setPrimaryContact($bob)` executed fine, as `primary_contact_id` got updated to Bob's `id`, but `primaryContact` still lists Alice.

Why is `primaryContact` not returning the correct object?

Comment: are you fetching record before or after update? Can you do `dd(App\Organization::find(17)->primaryContact` after the update is done and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your `setPrimaryContact` method won't update your table, because you call `$this->save`, not `$this->save()`, `save` is a method
- After `$org->setPrimaryContact($bob)`, you should call `$org-> primaryContact->refresh()` to get the updated record.

Comment: I updated it to `$this->save()` and called `$org->primaryContact->refresh()` which didn't work, but `$org->refresh()` does!  thanks a bunch!

Comment: also discovered I can call `$this->refresh()` from within `setPrimaryContact()` which does the trick as well.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. `refresh` will update current model and reload it's relations.