# Eloquent ORM - Why does Laravel not think these two objects are the same?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still very much new to Laravel.  After I was [able to get multiple Eloquent relationships defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54140432/4468423) between two models, I noticed it was possible to pass in an instance to a method in a parent model instance it didn't belong to.  So I thought it might be good to enforce that relationship within the method itself.

in Organization.php:

```
/**
 * @param \App\Contact The Contact to delete
 */
public function deleteContact(Contact $contact)
{
    if($contact->organization == $this)
    {
        $this->contacts->find($contact->id)->delete();
    }
    else
    {
        dd('Error: Contact ' . $contact->fname . ' ' . $contact->lname . ' #' . $contact->id . ' does not belong to Organization ' . $this->name . ' #' . $this->id);
    }
}
```

However, I kept getting the custom error message when passing in contacts that actually belonged, or at least I thought they did!  When I tested the relationship in `tinker`, it returned different instance `id`s for both Bob and Bob's organization.

```
>>> $org = Organization::find(17)
=> App\Organization {#2929
     id: 17,
     name: "Test Org",
     primary_contact_id: 33,
   }
>>> $org->contacts
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2925
     all: [
       App\Contact {#2926
         id: 33,
         organization_id: 17,
         fname: "Alice",
         lname: "Abbot",
       },
       App\Contact {#2943
         id: 34,
         organization_id: 17,
         fname: "Bob",
         lname: "Baker",
       },
     ],
   }
>>> $bob = Contact::find(34)
=> App\Contact {#2940
     id: 34,
     organization_id: 17,
     fname: "Bob",
     lname: "Baker",
   }
>>> $bob->organization == $org
=> false
>>> $bob->organization
=> App\Organization {#2932
     id: 17,
     name: "Test Org",
     primary_contact_id: 33,
   }
```

So apparently it is comparing two separate instances.  To get around this, I had to change the conditional to `$contact->organization->id == $this->id` which worked.  However, doing so is much less Eloquent.

1. Why are there two different instances being generated?  These are subsequent calls that should (in theory) produce the same instance (or so I thought).
2. Is this extra protection even necessary?  We're at least partially protected due to the inner code, but not something I can surround with `try`/`catch` and gracefully handle the violation -- I need to test first, then attempt delete.  (If the passed `Contact` isn't a valid related instance to the `Organization`, `find()` returns `null`, resulting in a PHP error and not an Exception.)  Is there a better way to do this, or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Why not compare using the organization id like `$bob->organization_id == $this->id`? No need to load the organization from the database just to compare it's id.

Comment: Could you give this a try instead? `$bob->organization->is($org);`

Comment: Eloquent will NOT provide the same instance of a Model everytime you query for it.  Just make sure that you understand that.  Just like calling `find` twice will not return the same memory, calling `find` will not return the same memory as when you retrieve the same resource through a relationship.

Comment: @Devon It may be a different instance, but the == comparison operator will return true if both models have the same values and are of the same class. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php. You're thinking of the === identity operator, which requires the same instance.

Comment: @NMahurin Yeah, I'm aware, but because of the varying data in models, it's not reliable.  I'd be wary ever using `==` unless it's a stdClass object.  But my comment above is regarding his question about different instances being generated.

Comment: @Devon all good, and from what I've seen from testing it is terribly unreliable. You're correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Laravel's perspective, we cannot just rely on the equality operator to compare objects, which, in the case of Eloquent models can be quite unreliable and difficult to compare.

As @Devon and @N Mahurin also rightly said, using equality operators to compare objects would work well if you are comparing stdClass objects which are more predictable.

This was a struggle back in the days. Fortunately, this [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/14281) made it into Laravel's core in 5.3.

To know if two models are essentially the same, Laravel checks if

1. The primary key is the same
2. The table is the same
3. The database connection is the same.

Based on this, we can assume that we are comparing two rows that are equal. So, in your case, the following should work:

```
$bob->organization->is($org);
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#comparing-models) on comparing models.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do some testing on that first question. It seems like when you call a relationship inside of the model, the relations array of that model instance is filled with that relation. Your `$this->contacts->find($contact->id)->delete();` is causing this. Even though you called the relation *after* the comparison. I was a little surprised by this behavior, but that seems to be the case. Since the two model instances are now containing different values (one has a filled relations array), the comparison fails. There is a new is() method though, see https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/comparing-model-equality-in-laravel. That may help you here.

There are a few different ways to handle the second question. I'd personally just roll up the testing in the already in use `if/else` like so:

```
if(($contact->organization == $this) && ($this->contacts->find($contact->id)?? false))
```

Using the ?? operator will return false if your `find()` comes back null.